# What are the options to distribute a Java application with data stored online?

Tags: java, web-services, java-web-start, juddi

I am developing a java application that will be distributed among several different end-users. Nevertheless, there are some variables that I want to store online so that everyone is accessing the same global attributes (I think this would mean creating a database, correct me if I'm wrong).

My GUI is built with javaFX and I am about to implement jUDDI since it's the only way I know to deploy a java application.

I would like to know if there is a simpler and more efficient way to distribute my application. I've found some information about java web start but I feel like there should be better alternatives.

Comment: Java Web Start is by far the best way to distribute a Java application, especially if you have some small parts you want to be able to update on your server.  I'm not sure why you think there should be something better.

Comment: I agree strongly with @VGR that [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) **is** the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!